# RxJS - filter not console the 'click' event on filter

Tags: jquery, rxjs

I am very new to `rxjs` I am trying to console the `click` events, for that i am using this function:

```
$(function(){

 Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
.filter(function(c) { 
  console.log('c', c); //but nothing consoles..?
})

});
```

But nothing consoles for me.. what is the issue? any one explain me the mistake what  i do here?

[Live Try](http://plnkr.co/edit/bb9pxSaLOBOcDxcnpPqm?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`subscribe`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subscription) to your `Observable`

> A Subscription is an object that represents a disposable resource,
>   usually the execution of an Observable.

```
var stream$ = Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent(document, 'click')
    .filter(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      return e;
    });

stream$.subscribe(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

[`Example`](http://plnkr.co/edit/QymD0alXdRTxgCJ1AKO0?p=preview)